# Removing columns from csv when cut and csvfilter both stop before finishing

Tags: csv, terminal

I'm trying to take a large csv file (800,000 rows, 160 columns). I'm trying to remove select columns, but keep all rows. I've tried two different methods--the standard cut command, and csvfilter--but neither of them will return all rows. In fact, they both return different numbers of rows, with cut returning a dozen or so more than csvfilter, but both a little over 4000.

I've looked at the original csv to try to see what might be making it choke, but I can't see anything: no quote marks in the row, no special characters.

Can anyone suggest a reliable method to remove columns from a csv or a way to more effectively troubleshoot csvfilter and/or cut? I'm mostly working on a Mac, but can work on Windows as well.

Comment: The title of your question mentions "stop before finishing"... is there an error from either?

Comment: No error at all. It just finishes and then when I open the output, it's only just over 4000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend GoCSV's [select](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#select) command.  It's already built for macOS/darwin, so go straight to [the latest release](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases/tag/v1.0.1) and downloading the binary of your choosing.

I'm not sure why **csvfilter** would truncate your file.  I'm especially skeptical that **cut** would eliminate any line, but I haven't tried 800K lines before.

### Testing cut; comparing GoCSV

Here's a Python script to generate a CSV, **large.csv**, that is 800_000 rows by 160 columns:

```py
with open('large.csv', 'w') as f:
    # Write header
    cols = ['Count']
    cols += [f'H{k+1}' for k in range(159)]
    f.write(','.join(cols) + '\n')

    # Write data
    for i in range(800_000):
        cols = [str(i+1)]
        cols += [f'C{k+1}' for k in range(159)]
        f.write(','.join(cols) + '\n')
```

Ensure large has 800K lines:

```sh
wc -l large.csv
  800001 large.csv
```

And with GoCSV's **dims** (dimensions) command:

```sh
gocsv dims large.csv 
Dimensions:
  Rows: 800000
  Columns: 160
```

(GoCSV always counts the first row/line as the "header", which doesn't have any effect for cutting/selecting columns)

And now cutting the columns:

```sh
time cut -d ',' -f1,160 large.csv > cut.csv
cut -d, -f1,160 large.csv > cut.csv  8.10s user 0.38s system 99% cpu 8.483 total
```

```sh
time gocsv select -c 1,160 large.csv > gocsv_select.csv
gocsv select -c 1,160 large.csv > gocsv_select.csv  5.25s user 2.55s system 106% cpu 7.322 total
```

Compare the two methods:

```sh
cmp gocsv_select.csv cut.csv
```

and since they are the same, looking at the head and tail of one counts for both:

```sh
head -n2 cut.csv 
Count,H159
1,C159

tail -n2 cut.csv 
799999,C159
800000,C159
```

So, both did what looks like the *right thing*, specifically **cut** didn't filter/drop any lines/rows.  And GoCSV, actually did it faster.

I'm curious what your **cut** command looks like, but I think the bigger point to stress is to use a CSV-aware tool whenever you can (*always*).

Comment: gocsv did exactly what I expected the other two to do: all rows returned. Thank you! This is great!

Comment: Wow! How weird, especially that **csvfilter** failed. Well, glad it worked!